# Not an Expected Result Loop of a Structure in c

Tags: c, loops, structure

I am working on a simple C program which is to create a loop of a structure.
So I have a structure of a `Students` with name, age, and grade.

So the output will be something like this:

```
Enter name of student 1:
Enter age of student 1:
Enter Grade of student 1:

Enter name of student 2:
Enter age of student 2:
Enter Grade of student 2:
```

But after I input the grade of Student 1, it skipped The name of student 2 so I got this instead:

```
Enter name of student 1:
Enter age of student 1:
Enter Grade of student 1:

Enter name of student 2: Enter age of student 2:
```

[image: Structure Loop Picture]

And I am using DevC++, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student {
    char name[50];   // declare name using array
    int age;
    int grade;
};

int main ()
{
    struct student info[3];   //declare 3 students [3]
    int i;

    for(i=1;i<=3;i++) {    // this is for the looping, student 1, student 2, student 3
        printf("Enter name for student %d : ",i);
        scanf("%s",info[i].name);   // called struct using "." (dot)
        printf("Enter age for sudent %d : ",i);
        scanf("%d",&info[i].age);
        printf("Enter grade for student %d : ",i);
        scanf("%d",&info[i].grade);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Can someone find what is wrong with my code? or please help a suggestion to solve this problem to get the expected result.

Comment: you should use `fgets` rather than `scanf` to read strings. Also don't tag as both c and c++, you are using c, there is no such language as "c/c++"

Comment: when i = 3 you'll probably get a segmentation fault. Indexes start at 0, your loop will use i = 1, 2, 3, but the valid range is 0,1,2

Comment: Add some newlines '\n' to your printf statements.

Comment: I see I will consider it, thanks. btw what should I do if the valid range was 0,1,2? I am a begginer so please do help me here.

Comment: As pointed out by Gerado Zinno, arrays in C are always base 0, so change the loop to read for(I=0; I<3; I++) {

Comment: `B` is not a **decimal integer**. Store the grade into a `char`, use `" %c"` with space before as the format.

Comment: And the input/output session, you *must* copy-paste that next time as text into the question itself!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Sorry I just join this community, and I will keep that in mind next time, thanks.

Comment: It is because it is hard to see errors in pictures and to copy paste the exact same input, and to really see if it is 8 or B...

Comment: I see you got a point there. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Tried your code and it work succesfully, I tried to compare it with what you have done.

And The result is you declare `scanf("%d",&info[i].grade);`

which is received an **integer** input. but when I see your picture your Input was a **Character**

So Just Change Your Input with an Integer on `Enter grade for student i`

Comment: Never expected To see this answer, thanks. I'm glad that you pointed that out for me, I tried it and it proved to be true.

What I actually need is scan a Char Value on grade, thanks.

Comment: @hyde Maybe you are right, I'm glad you said it, so I could improve my knowledge.

Comment: @SinHalloween I'm glad able to help.

Comment: If you use `%c` to read a character (not sure if that is what you are suggesting), it will also read whitespace characters, so you need to have a space before it (read `scanf` docs for details on what it does, exactly).

Comment: No I'm using " %c" instead (with a space).

Answer (score 3):

Multiple suggestions of your code:

When using `scanf` to input data, always check its return value to make sure sufficient data is input correctly, for example, when you input `B` for the `int grade` field, it returns zero instead of one:

```
int r = scanf("%d", &info[i].grade);
printf("%d\n", r); // 0
```

Also as said in the comments, when you input strings try use `fgets`, because it is more secure and will not stop at spaces. `scanf` does not check for buffer overflow.

Also, in your `for` loop, you are accessing out of bounds of the array `info`, you have to start from `0`.

Try the following:

```
int main ()
{
    struct student info[3];   //declare 3 students [3]
    int i;
    int r;
    for(i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("Enter name for student %d : ",i);
        fgets(info[i].name, 50, stdin);
        printf("Enter age for sudent %d : ",i);
        r = scanf("%d", &info[i].age);
        if (r < 1) {
            printf("input error, exiting\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Enter grade for student %d : ",i);
        r = scanf("%d", &info[i].grade);
        if (r < 1) {
            printf("input error, retry\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code in your answer is indexing array out of bounds...

Comment: Nice suggestion, by checking its return value I can do it more accurate. is that also work for a lot of data like 100 or even 1000 data?

Comment: @SinHalloween yes, it works for any data.

Comment: @hyde careless copied that for loop from OP, fixed, thanks for checking.

Comment: Thanks, I will make sure I will upvote it when I get 15 reputations.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the [answer by Serafin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53775741/9658875): (Good catch, BTW!)

When you input a non-number into your scanf call,

```
    printf("Enter grade for student %d : ",i);
```

scanf will fail to read the input (see comment by hyde, thanks) 
<strike>scanf will skip all inputs that don't match the input pattern provided until it hits newline.</strike> Anything that was not <strike>matched</strike> read remains in the input buffer. Therefore, the subsequent call to scanf receives the old content from the previous input, which does get matched in this case.

Comment: Scanf will not skip inputs that don't match the pattern. It will fail with parse error and leave the unparsed input into the buffer.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. The effect concerning the input buffer, however, is the same.

Answer (score 1):

grade is **int** but you type a **char** ('B', It's like 8 :D), I modity three line:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student {
    char name[50];   // declare name using array
    int age;
    char grade; // int -> char
};

int main ()
{
    struct student info[3];   //declare 3 students [3]
    int i;

    for(i=1;i<=3;i++) {    // this is for the looping, student 1, student 2, student 3
        printf("Enter name for student %d : ",i);
        scanf("%s",info[i].name);   // called struct using "." (dot)
        printf("Enter age for sudent %d : ",i);
        scanf("%d",&info[i].age);
        getchar(); // reade '\n' after type age
        printf("Enter grade for student %d : ",i);
        scanf("%c",&info[i].grade); // %d -> %c
    }
    return 0;

}
```